# VB.net and SentinelOne clash

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, antivirus

I built a scraper app. It downloads the sourcecode of a website. The extracted relevant data is then pumped into a Photoshop file, to avoid manual data typing.

Since a few weeks, we have SentinelOne. It immediately blocks every PC that runs my app.
I have certain grabs of what SentinelOne says. The people at Sentinel suggest unsafe options to avoid the problem or using a Certificate. So I am thinking of that route.

A. I don't know how Certificates work exactly. B. It doesn't seem to be free.

Our administrator however, thinks that the things my app does, are the actual problem. And he says that should be changed to avoid the problem.

Thing is, I can no longer develop anything with Visual Studio as SentinelOne blocks the created apps. And my administrator won't budge.

Although I understand little of Visual Studio, I can't do without it: I MUST write my own amateurish apps. Maybe someone can tell me an easy free solution to avoid Sentinel from acting up?

[image: Malware suspicion]

[image: Dynamic AI detection]

[image: Signing problems]

Comment: first check your event viewer log any error in application.

Comment: Where and how? In windows or Visual Studio? The app normally works fine.

Comment: Please check in windows

Comment: But where must I look in the logs? There are many "folders"?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below image goto windows logs->application.
[image: Eventviewer]

Comment: Ah well it is not listed there. The app has no errors.

Answer (score 0):

For now, we have put all computers that use this app, in a Sentinel group. Only these PCs are allowed to run the app from a specific folder. Alas that means I can only edit this specific app when needed but building new apps will pose problems again.
For now, this issue is solved with a partly and ugly workaround.
More suggestions about a healthy workflow, are welcome.